# Create DM on message [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that deletes the message content and send it back to the user if it's not the word "role".

Code is working fine. The message gets deleted if it's not "role" and I do received a dm with the deleted message, but I don't know if I'm doing it right because I get this error "AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'".

Here's my code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        dm = await message.author.create_dm()
        if not message.guild:
            return
        if not message.channel.name == 'roles':
            return
        elif message.channel.name == 'roles' and message.content != 'role':
            if message.author.bot:
                pass
            else:
                await dm.send(f'{message.content}')
                await message.delete()
```

Comment: ClientUser is the bot user, which is why you get the error, since ClientUser class does now have a function called create_dm. Your first statement should be checking if the message.author is bot

Comment: Thank you for replying! Figured it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord bots can't send DM's to eachother, only to `Users`. Your bot is trying to send a DM to itself, which it can't. You need to check with an if-statement if the message's author is a bot or not.

You're already doing this later on in your code, to see if it should send the message or not, but the `create_dm()` function at the top will have already failed at that point (as it can't create a dm), so it will never get there.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return # Ignore bot messages

    if not message.guild:
        return

    if not message.channel.name == 'roles':
        return

    elif message.content != 'role':
        await message.author.send(message.content)
        await message.delete()
```

PS. A few more things to note here:

- You can just use `User.send()` instead of `create_dm()` & `dm.send()`.
- An `f-string` with nothing but the content can just be the content itself (`f"{word}"` == `word`, or `str(word)` in case it's not a string).
- You have an `if` checking if the channel name is not "roles", and afterwards in the `elif` you check if it *is* - if it wouldn't be "roles" then it would've gotten into the first `if` & returned so the second one is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You really helped me! One question, if I were to use a command with message arg example command is role(self, ctx, *, message), how should I put it in elif message.content != 'role':? It only allows the command itself, but when you add a message it sends the whole thing again.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you again!